# Why my mysql search query does not returning anything?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables,

`posts` table

```
create table posts (id int, calories int, INGREDIENTS INT, SERVE INT);
INSERT INTO POSTS VALUES(1,100,5,1);
INSERT INTO POSTS VALUES(2,100,5,1);
```

`post_translations` table

```
CREATE TABLE post_translations (id int, post_id int, language_id int, `group` varchar(50), `key` varchar(50), `value` varchar(50));
insert into post_translations  values (2,1,1, 'title_group','post_tagline','spicy and tasty chicken');
insert into post_translations  values (6,2,1, 'title_group','post_tagline','spicy and tasty mutton');
```

`post_tags` table

```
create table post_tags(id int, post_id int, tag varchar(50));
insert into post_tags values(7,1,'chicken');
```

I am trying following query to search result which should match from `post_translations` or `post_tags`

```
SELECT  posts.id, posts.`image`
FROM posts
JOIN post_translations ON  post_translations.`post_id` = posts.`id`
JOIN post_tags ON  post_tags.post_id = posts.id
WHERE post_tags.`tag` 
LIKE '%spicy%' 
OR post_translations.`value` 
LIKE '%spicy%' GROUP BY posts.id
```

But it is returning nothing, also there is no error. Also I want to find a way to further filter record in the same query. I have one more table which is `posts_country`

```
create table posts_country (id int, post_id int, country int);
insert into posts_country values (2,1,2);
insert into posts_country values (3,1,3);
insert into posts_country values (4,2,2);
insert into posts_country values (5,2,3);
```

I want to further filter posts by country id, like following query returns posts of specific country.

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.`image` 
FROM posts
WHERE id IN(
      SELECT post_id FROM posts_country WHERE country_id = 1 GROUP BY post_id
)
```

Can someone please help, I would like to appreciate. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @nbk I will take next time thank you

Comment: @cartli Instead of images please share sample data in text format along with table structures for better understanding of the problem. And it would be better if you share db-fiddle link or something like that.

Comment: Retract the conditions in your query one by one until you get the desired result. That's the usual way I find out which part of the query is not working as I intended. Then from there is where I'll start the troubleshooting. About the downvote you're getting, you must understand that SO is a community of people needing and providing help. The traffic is very high so most people won't bother trying to help if they can't reproduce/replicate your situation. In short, if it were you, would you rather to re-type codes/data from photo or copy & paste them from the question?

Comment: @cartli I have edited your question. Please try to uploading images in question so that you can dodge the downvotes and people can help you more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

You are inner joining all the tables. So only those rows will be returned which fulfil all the conditions. **post_tags** table has only one post and the tag is not **spicy**. So no rows will be selected from this table and that's why query is returning nothing.
Instead of join you may use left join. Or you may also try below query:

```
  SELECT  posts.*
    FROM posts
    where (id in (select post_id from post_translations where post_translations.value
    LIKE '%spicy%' )
    or id in (select post_id from post_tags where tag LIKE '%spicy%' ))
and id IN(
      SELECT post_id FROM posts_country WHERE country_id = 2 )
```

This will return all your desired rows. Now if you want to use group by then you must use some aggregation in select list.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but in this way I am getting duplicated records, i want to get unique records.

Comment: Does posts have duplicate id? I thought ID is the primary key.

Comment: I mean in post translation there would be many ids right and post tags also, thanks for your answer +1

Comment: There will be multiple rows for post_translation or post_tags but query will return rows only from posts table where there should be no duplicate records. For example if post_tags or post_translation is returning more than one rows for a specific post_id ultimately this query will return one row for that post_id form posts table.

Comment: You are right, i tested. Can you give me one more favor, how can I filter it further, for example if i need records which belongs to `country_id=2`. you can read my question for reference.

Comment: Your condition for country was perfect if you remove group by clause

Comment: The cure seems worse than the disease. :-(